Interaction between inputs from different tippy's
I'd like to interact the inputs of different tippys, but I can't do it.
For example, in tippy 1 there is this input:
<input type=“radio” name=“thousandSeparator” value=“comma” class=“commaBlock1”>

And in tippy 2 there is this:
<input type=“radio” name=“decimalSeparator” value=“commaDec” class=“commaBlock2”>

I tried the following, when one is enabled, it would disable the other option, that is, when I select commaBlock1 from tippy 1, in tippy2 commaBlock2 would disable it (and vice versa). But the interaction doesn't work.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tippy.js Nested Example</title>
    <!-- Tippy.js CSS -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6/themes/light.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="openTippy">Open Tippy</button>

    <!-- Tippy.js and Popper.js CDN -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            // Initialize Tippy Principal
            tippy('#openTippy', {
                content: `
                    <div>
                        <button id="openTippy1">Open Tippy 1</button>
                        <button id="openTippy2">Open Tippy 2</button>
                    </div>
                `,
                theme: 'light',
                trigger: 'click',
                interactive: true,
                placement: 'bottom',
                allowHTML: true,
                onShow(instance) {
                    // Initialize Tippy 1
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        tippy('#openTippy1', {
                            content: `
                                <div>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="thousandSeparator" value="comma" class="commaBlock1">
                                        Comma
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="thousandSeparator" value="dot" class="dotBlock1">
                                        Dot
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            `,
                            theme: 'light',
                            trigger: 'click',
                            interactive: true,
                            allowHTML: true,
                            placement: 'bottom',
                            appendTo: instance.popper,
                            onShow() {
                                document.querySelectorAll('input[name="thousandSeparator"]').forEach(input => {
                                    input.addEventListener('change', () => {
                                        const selectedValue = document.querySelector('input[name="thousandSeparator"]:checked').value;
                                        if (selectedValue === 'comma') {
                                            document.querySelectorAll('input[name="decimalSeparator"]').forEach(decInput => {
                                                if (decInput.value === 'commaDec') {
                                                    decInput.checked = false;
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }, 0);

                    // Initialize Tippy 2
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        tippy('#openTippy2', {
                            content: `
                                <div>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="decimalSeparator" value="commaDec" class="commaBlock2">
                                        Comma Decimal
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="decimalSeparator" value="dotDec" class="dotBlock2">
                                        Dot Decimal
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            `,
                            theme: 'light',
                            trigger: 'click',
                            interactive: true,
                            allowHTML: true,
                            placement: 'bottom',
                            appendTo: instance.popper,
                            onShow() {
                                document.querySelectorAll('input[name="decimalSeparator"]').forEach(input => {
                                    input.addEventListener('change', () => {
                                        const selectedValue = document.querySelector('input[name="decimalSeparator"]:checked').value;
                                        if (selectedValue === 'commaDec') {
                                            document.querySelectorAll('input[name="thousandSeparator"]').forEach(thouInput => {
                                                if (thouInput.value === 'comma') {
                                                    thouInput.checked = false;
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>




I'm not quite sure about your disable logic, as I don't see any reference to disabled in your code.
Additionally, there is an issue in your code where
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="thousandSeparator"]') 

seems to always return an empty NodeList in onShow method.
You might consider placing this code inside a setTimeout block to address the issue.
